# Exception with nested model-driven forms: "No value accessor for"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to code a angular2 **model-driven form** whose model implies a **nested structure** and I get the following exception:

```
No value accessor for 'signupInfo -> userAccount -> userAccountType'
```

Here is the relevant part from the component class:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      signupInfo: this.formBuilder.group({
        userAccount: this.formBuilder.group({
          userAccountType: [this.signupInfo.userAccount.userAccountType, [Validators.required]],
          email: [this.signupInfo.userAccount.email, [Validators.required /*,Validators.pattern(EMAIL_PATTERN), EmailValidators.emailAvailable()*/]],
          firstName: [this.signupInfo.userAccount.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(35), /*,Validators.pattern(FIRST_NAME_PATTERN)*/]]
        }),
        plainPassword: [this.signupInfo.plainPassword, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        placeId: [this.signupInfo.placeId, [Validators.required]]
      })
    });
  }
```

Here is the relevant part from the component template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="signup()" class="col-xs-12" novalidate role="form">
    <h4>{{'SIGNUP_FORM.ROLE_PREFIX' | translate}}</h4>
    <fieldset formGroupName="signupInfo">
        <fieldset formGroupName="userAccount">
            <div class="btn-group Choix col-xs-12 text-center" [ngClass]="getCssClasses(signupForm, signupRole)">
                <label class="btn StateButton col-xs-6"
                       uib-btn-radio="'PARENTS_TYPE'"
                       formControlName="userAccountType">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/parents.svg"/>
                    <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM.' + 'ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS' | translate}}</span>
                </label>
                <label class="btn StateButton col-xs-6"
                       uib-btn-radio="'CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPE'"
                       formControlName="userAccountType">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/professionel.svg"/>
                    <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM.' + 'ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCARE_WORKER' | translate}}</span>
                </label>

                <div [hidden]="signupForm.valid">
                    <div *ngIf="signupForm?.controls?.signupInfo?.controls?.userAccountType?.errors?.required" class="control-label">
                      {{'SIGNUP_FORM.ROLE_REQUIRED'| translate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: It must be noted that my `bootstrap()` method call does include the following:

```
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
```

and I still get this error. Also all my form related classes import from:

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/forms";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing my form to use **radio inputs** as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="signup()" class="col-xs-12" novalidate role="form">
    <h4>{{'SIGNUP_FORM.ROLE_PREFIX' | translate}}</h4>
    <fieldset formGroupName="signupInfo">
        <fieldset formGroupName="userAccount">
            <div class="btn-group Choix col-xs-12 text-center" [ngClass]="getCssClasses(signupForm, signupRole)">
                <input class="btn StateButton col-xs-6"
                       id="parent"
                       type="radio"
                       value="'PARENTS_TYPE'"
                       title="Parents"
                       formControlName="userAccountType"/>
                <label for="parent">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/parents.svg"/>
                      <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM.' + 'ROLE_BASIC_PARENTS' | translate}}</span>
                </label>
                <input class="btn StateButton col-xs-6"
                       id="childcare_worker"
                       type="radio"
                       value="'CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPE'"
                       title="Childcare worker"
                       formControlName="userAccountType"/>
                <label for="childcare_worker">
                      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/media/img/professionel.svg"/>
                      <span class="help-block">{{'DOMAIN_ENUM.' + 'ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCARE_WORKER' | translate}}</span>
                </label>
                <div [hidden]="signupForm.valid">
                    <div *ngIf="signupForm?.controls?.signupInfo?.controls?.userAccountType?.errors?.required" class="control-label">
                      {{'SIGNUP_FORM.ROLE_REQUIRED'| translate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the issue was sorted.